# If$ ( \sigma(n) = 2n+1) \rightarrow n$ is odd.

Tags: number-theory

Prove, that if$ ( \sigma(n) = 2n+1) \rightarrow n$ is odd.

$\sigma(n) $ should mean the following function: $\sigma(n)= \sum_{d|n, 1 \le d \le n} d$

For example: $\sigma (12) = 1+2+3+4+6+12 = 28$.

From definition, we say that $\sigma(0) = 0, \sigma(1) =1$.

I have no idea how to prove the statement above. Any help would be nice. :)

Comment: For odd $n$, $\sigma(n)$ need not be odd, $\sigma(3) = 4,\, \sigma(27) = 40$.

Comment: True that, then I have absolutely no idea. :D

Comment: $\sigma(n)$ is odd if and only if $n = 2^k \cdot m^2$ with an odd $m$. If $m = 1$, we have $\sigma(2^k) = 2^{k+1}-1$, so we need $m > 1$. But how to prove that we must have $k = 0$, I don't see yet.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I do not think there are any solutions to $\sigma(n) = 1 + 2n.$ The question becomes, what is the source of this problem?

Comment: @WillJagy It is an open problem whether such numbers exist. Such numbers are called quasiperfect.

Comment: @atvin Did you actually mean $\sigma(n) = 2n+1$, or did you just mean "$\sigma(n)$ is odd" ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiperfect_number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that this was a question on the 1976 Putnam competition. You can read the proof [here](http://www.math-olympiad.com/37th-putnam-mathematical-competition-1976-problems.htm#12).

In fact, this shows that is must be an odd square.

Comment: wythagoras, thanks for your comment above. I knew i had answered on something similar, years ago, but could not remember any relevant names.